# How to increase each number in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to search a string for any numbers in it and increase the numbers by 1. So that this `'sermon[thesis][1][name][2]'` becomes `'sermon[thesis][2][name][3]'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
"sermon[thesis][1][name][2]".replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function(match, number) {
    return "[" + (Number(number) + 1) + "]";
});
```

Working demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHUeT/).

**EDIT:**

To increment the last number, you would add a dollar sign `$` before the last `/`, here's a demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5bwV/).

Comment: Or `+number` instead of `Number(number)`.

Comment: Hey, what if I wanted to replace only the last number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`, it can actually take a function as the replacement "string".

```
var str = 'sermon[thesis][1][name][2]';
str = str.replace(/(\d+)/g, function(a){
   return parseInt(a,10) + 1;
});
console.log(str); //'sermon[thesis][2][name][3]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace()` function to match any number with a regular expression and then return that value incremented by 1 to replace it:

```
var string = '[1][2]';
string.replace(/[0-9]+/g,function(e){return parseInt(e,10)+1})); //Returns [2][3]
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sPHb4/1/)**

Comment: `parseInt(e)` should be `parseInt(e, 10)`.

Comment: @Rocket, I believe it can be omitted and uses the default values. Also, it helps for readability in this case.

Comment: I _can_ be omitted, but shouldn't.  The default value isn't always what you want.  `parseInt('13')` gives you `13` like you'd expect, but `parseInt('013')` gives you `11`.  `013` starts with a `0` so it's assumed to be octal (base 8).  `parseInt('013', 10)` on the other hand returns `13`.

Comment: Doh - that's what I get for hopping all over this site. Fixed.

Comment: It's ok, it's the morning.  I think we all need another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var str = "sermon[thesis][1][name][2]";
var newStr = str.replace(new RegExp("\\d+", "g"), function (n) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) + 1;
});
```

Basicly, the function would be called with the text been captured by the expression `\d+`，the text return from the function would be use to replace the captured text.