# How to replace every number in a string with a different number?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase each number in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432865/how-to-increase-each-number-in-a-string)

In JavaScript how could I replace every number in a string with that number `+ 20`?

So, this string: `"min: 300px and max: 600px, min: 800px"`

Would end up as `"min: 320px and max: 620px, min: 820px"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the shortest version:

```
"min: 300px and max: 600px, min: 800px".replace(/\d+/g, function(c) {
    return parseInt(c, 10) + 20;
});
```

Comment: `return +c + 20` is even shorter.

Comment: @SalmanA That's exactly what I wrote first but then decided to change to `parseInt(c, 10)` for more readability.

Comment: Nice answer. Never saw such implementation. Thanks.